# How to show comments on an HTML exported from Org-Mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html, exporting

I'm working on updating the social status of a company.

The original document has been made with Org-Mode and exported to PDF.

In order to keep track of the modifications I'm putting the old parts into comments.

```
This is an updated part
# This is an original part
```

Ultimately, the old parts won't appear in the final new PDF. But before that, I have to send an HTML version (for reviewing), where the comments will appear. The reviewer doesn't use Emacs/Org-Mode, that's why I thought of sending him the document in the body of an email copied from an HTML export.

How could I export an HTML showing the commented old parts?

I read the Org-Mode manual (mainly [Export Settings](https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-Settings.html) and [The Export Dispatcher](https://orgmode.org/manual/The-Export-Dispatcher.html)), but I didn't find the option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to replace or delete the comment symbol when exporting to HTML.

```lisp
(defun show-comments (backend)
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'html)
    (save-excursion
      (while (not (eobp))
        (forward-line)
        (when (looking-at org-comment-regexp)
          (replace-match ": " ))))))

(add-to-list 'org-export-before-parsing-hook 'show-comments)
```

The following should make comments red.

```lisp
(defun show-comments-in-red (backend)
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'html)
    (save-excursion
      (while (not (eobp))
        (forward-line)
        (when (and (null (org-at-keyword-p))
                   (looking-at "^[ \t]*#\\(?: \\|$\\)*\\(.+\\)*"))
          (replace-match "#\+html: <div style=\"color:red;\">\\1</div>\n"))))))

(add-to-list 'org-export-before-parsing-hook 'show-comments-in-red)
```

Comment: Thanks. So with this code, all `# `will be replaced by `: `?

Comment: When I execute the code, I have the following message : `progn: Symbol’s value as variable is void: org-export-before-parsing-functionsInvalid face attribute :bold t`

Comment: Would it be possible to also change the color of the exported commented parts?

Comment: Updated. BTW I don't see that error and I'm not sure what's causing it.

Comment: Thank you. When I execute the second code I don't have any errors. Though I don't know how to use it...

Comment: When I add `(interactive)` and do `M-x show-comments-in-red` I have the following error: `funcall-interactively: Wrong number of arguments: (lambda (backend) (interactive) (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'html) (save-excursion (while (not (eobp)) (forward-line) (when (looking-at org-comment-regexp) (replace-match "") (insert "#+html: <div style=\"color:red;\">") (org-forward-paragraph) (insert "#+html: </div>")))))), 0`

Comment: You also need: `(add-to-list 'org-export-before-parsing-functions 'show-comments-in-red)`. No need to make the function interactive.

Comment: When I add the `add-to-list` line, I have the previous error message : `progn: Symbol’s value as variable is void: org-export-before-parsing-functions`. How could I help you find its cause?

Comment: Even when I do `emacs -q` I have the same error. My Emacs version is 28.2 and I'm on GNU/Linux (arch).

Comment: You may have to require the ox library with `(require 'ox)`.

Comment: Adding `(require 'ox)` to init didn't solve the issue. Also, I already had `ox-extra` activated. Does it work on your computer with `emacs -q`?

Comment: It doesn't. There's no org-export-before-parsing-functions in Org version 9.5. Try replacing `org-export-before-parsing-functions` with `org-export-before-parsing-hook` and see if that works.

Comment: My Org-Mode version is 9.5.5. When I replace `org-export-before-parsing-functions` with `org-export-before-parsing-hook` I don't have any errors, but it doesn't behave as expected: If I have a series of lines starting with `#`, the first is in red without `#`, the second is in black with `#`, the third is in red without `#`, etc.

Comment: I normally leave one line empty between comments. Anyway, try now and see if that works.

Comment: It works fine thank you, except that the preamble (#+TITLE:..., #+OPTIONS:..., etc.) also appears in red now. But it's ok. Maybe you could edit the answer explaining that `org-export-before-parsing-functions` should be replaced by `org-export-before-parsing-hook` for Org-Mode < 9.6.

Comment: Thanks. It should skip keywords now.

Comment: Thank @jagrg, I added a code to toggle the functionality in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

- Function that export (`HTML`) text commented with `#` as blocks (code from @jagrg):

```lisp
(defun comments-as-blocks (backend)
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'html)
    (save-excursion
      (while (not (eobp))
        (forward-line)
        (when (looking-at org-comment-regexp)
          (replace-match ": " ))))))
```

- If you want the comments to be shown in the exported format, regardless of the export backend, use this function instead:

```lisp
(defun comments-as-blocks (backend)
  (save-excursion
    (while (not (eobp))
      (forward-line)
      (when (looking-at org-comment-regexp)
      (replace-match ": " )))))
```

- Function that allows to activate (toggle) or desactivate `#` comments exports as blocks (replace `org-export-before-parsing-hook` with `org-export-before-parsing-functions` when Org-Mode ≥ 9.6):

```lisp
(defun mda/toggle-comments-export ()
  (interactive)
  (if (get 'mda/toggle-comments-export 'state)
      (progn
        (setq org-export-before-parsing-hook (remove 'comments-as-blocks org-export-before-parsing-hook))
        (put 'mda/toggle-comments-export 'state nil))
    (progn
      (add-to-list 'org-export-before-parsing-hook 'comments-as-blocks)
      (put 'mda/toggle-comments-export 'state t))))
```